# Subscribe to Action in generic class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to subscribe to an event in a generic class. Below is the code of my extended List class. The Action `OnEntityDisable` in `IEntity` expects a `IEntity` as a parameter.

I get this error message:

> Expected a method with void RemoveItem(IEntity) signature

However, `T` is a `IEntity` in my class as you can see: `: IList<T> where T : IEntity`. What am I doing wrong?

```
public interface IEntity
{
    Action<IEntity> OnEntityDisable { get; set; }   
}

public class SelectionList<T> : IList<T> where T : IEntity
{
    private readonly IList<T> _entities;

    public SelectionList()
    {
        _entities = new List<T>(32);
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return;

        item.OnEntityDisable += RemoveItem; // This line throws an error

        _entities.Add(item);
    }

    public void RemoveItem(T item)
    {
        if (Count <= 0 || item == null)
            return false;

        _entities.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `SelectionList` seems strange. Is it an `IList` or does it contain an `IList`? You probably don't want both, yet your code suggest otherwise. Best to have an internal list.

Comment: I use this as an extra layer. If you have a suggestion to optimize, I'd like to hear :)

Comment: When Implementing IList you must, of course, implement all it's properties and methods. (Lucky for you it's not a lot, but still). Are you sure you really need all of them?

Comment: The only methods I edited are Add,Remove, Clear and the Indexer. I also added some custom methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue of contravariance. Every `T` is an `IEntity`, but not every `IEntity` is a `T`. Your event will guarantee you, that the argument is an `IEntity`, but it can not guarantee you that it is a `T`. Since `RemoveItem` wants a `T`, it does not work.

Making `T` contravariant is not an option, because `SelectionList` is a class and contravariance only works with interfaces and also because you couldn't inherit from `List<T>`, because the list's `T` is not contravariant.

You have three options to solve it:

**Change `RemoveItem`**

You can change `RemoveItem` to accept an `IEntity` instead of a `T`:

```
public void RemoveItem(IEntity item)
{
    if (Count <= 0 || item == null)
        return;

    _entities.Remove((T)item);
}
```

**Use a lambda expression as event handler**

Since changing `RemoveItem` changes the class interface, this might not be what you want. You can help yourself out by leaving it the way it is and do the necessary type cast in a lambda expression:

```
item.OnEntityDisable += item => RemoveItem((T)item);
```

**Make `IEntity` generic**

You can make the `IEntity` interface generic itself and pass the type parameter in the constraint:

```
public interface IEntity<T>
{
    Action<T> OnEntityDisable { get; set; }   
}
```

And then

```
public class SelectionList<T> : IList<T> where T : IEntity<T>
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: I went for the first solution. It was in my case the best option to implement it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While `T` is `IEntity` when you subscribe to the event of the interface the implementer of `IEntity` does not have any restriction to force it to pass a `T` as the event argument. It could pass any class that implements `IEntity`. .

There are two solution:

1. Make `IEntity` generic to ensure the type of the event argument, and use a more restrictive type constraint:

Code:

```
public interface IEntity<T>
{
    Action<T> OnEntityDisable { get; set; }
}
public class SelectionList<T> : IList<T> where T : IEntity<T>
{ }
```

2. Use an intermediate delegate and cast the argument to the expected type:

Code:

```
item.OnEntityDisable += e => RemoveItem((T)e);
```

The first solution is more type safe but it may be more of a hassle to work with. The second solution relies on the implementation of `IEntity` to behave well even if there is no type contract to force it to do so. Ultimately it depends on you which solution you choose.